# What does `<?=` mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I recently found some PHP code that looked like this:

```php
<?= getValueFromKey("Smith, Jane") ?>
```

Does anyone know what `<?=` means or the difference between it and `<?php`?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: It's a shortcut for `<?php echo getValueFromKey("Smith, Jane"); ?>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: I don't think so, there is a mountain of data in that one, and I can't even find it if I search for it.